# where do i get .aidl file while working in titanium framework for android?

Tags: titanium-mobile, android-2.2-froyo, aidl

The aidl tool converts the .aidl file to java interface which helps to make .apk file. 
I want to know from where do i get the .aidl file ? Does it come from android Sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken care of for you by the android SDK. You don't ever have to worry about this even when you're developing natively.